# scrapy item data not storing in databse postgresql

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data and store it in a postgresql database. The code extracts data correctly and stores it in a file but it does not show up in table in database. The URL I am trying to scrape is-
[https://www.gizbot.com/mobile-brands-in-india/'](https://www.gizbot.com/mobile-brands-in-india/%27)

spider.py

```
class MobilesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mobiles"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.gizbot.com/mobile-brands-in-india/',
            
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'mobiles-%s.html' % page
        mob = response.xpath('.//div[has-class("all-brands-block-desc-brand")]/text()').getall()
        im = list(response.css('div.all-brands-block'))
        res = dict(zip(mob, im))
        for mobile, i in res.items():

            with open(filename, 'a') as f:
                f.write("%s %s\n" % (mobile, "gizbot.com"+str(i.css('img::attr("data-pagespeed-lazy-src")').extract())))
            self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

pipelines.py

```
class MobilesPipeline:

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        hostname = 'localhost'
        username = 'postgres'
        password = 'postgres'  # your password
        database = 'postgres'
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database)
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.cur.close()
        self.connection.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cur.execute("insert into mobiles(name,image) values(%s,%s)", (item['name'], item['image']))
        self.connection.commit()
        return item
```

I need to store the brand name and img source in the database.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provided, you probably haven't enabled your pipeline in your spider's settings.  For the `process_item` method to be called, the pipeline must be active, to do this you need to add the following config to your `settings.py`

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.pipelines.MobilesPipeline': 300,
}
```

- Notice you need to replace `myproject.` with your project's name.
- The integer determine the order in which the pipelines run, from lower valued to higher valued classes.

Here are the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#activating-an-item-pipeline-component) if you need more info.

Comment: i have enabled it in my settings.py.It still doesn't work.

Comment: Please, update your question to include the relevant part of your settings, as they are relevant to the question. With the information so far, I agree with @renatodvc’s guess.